# Speeding up this PySCIPOpt routine for a Mixed Integer Program

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization, scip, quadratic-programming

I'm writing code to find [median orders](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Frederic.Havet/publi/median.pdf) of [tournaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)#:%7E:text=A%20tournament%20is%20a%20directed,in%20an%20undirected%20complete%20graph.), given a tournament T with n vertices, a median order is an ordering of the vertices of T such that it maximices the number of edges pointing in the 'increasing' direction with respect to the ordering.

In particular if the vertex set of T is {0,...,n-1}, the following integer problem (maximizing over the set of permutations) yields an optimal answer to the problem where Q is also a boolean n by n matrix.

[image]

I've implemented a linealization of this problem, noting that Q is a permutation, the following python code works, but my computer can't handle graphs that are as small as 10 vertices, where i would expect to have fast answers, is there any relatively easy way to speed up this computation?.

```
import numpy as np
from pyscipopt import Model,quicksum
from networkx.algorithms.tournament import random_tournament as rt
import math


# Some utilities to define the adjacency matrix of an oriented graph

def adjacency_matrix(t,order):
    n = len(order)
    adj_t = np.zeros((n,n))
    for e in t.edges:
        adj_t[order.index(e[0]),order.index(e[1])] = 1 
    return adj_t

# Random tournaments to instanciate the problem

def random_tournament(n):
    r_t = rt(n)
    adj_t = adjacency_matrix(r_t,list(range(n)))
    return r_t, adj_t

###############################################################
############# PySCIPOpt optimization Routine ##################
###############################################################

n = 5 # some arbitrary size parameter
t,adj_t = random_tournament(n)
 
model = Model()
p,w,r = {},{},{}

# Defining model variables and weights
for k in range(n):
    for l in range(n):
        p[k,l] = model.addVar(vtype='B')
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(i,n):
                r[i,k,l,j] = model.addVar(vtype='C')
                w[i,k,l,j] = adj_t[k][l]
                
for i in range(n):
    # Forcing p to be a permutation 
    model.addCons(quicksum(p[s,i] for s in range(n))==1)
    model.addCons(quicksum(p[i,s] for s in range(n))==1)
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            for l in range(n):
                # Setting r[i,k,l,j] = min(p[i,k],p[l,j])
                model.addCons(r[i,k,l,j] <= p[k,i])
                model.addCons(r[i,k,l,j] <= p[l,j])

# Set the objective function
model.setObjective(quicksum(r[i,k,l,j]*w[i,k,l,j] for i in range(n) for j in range(i,n) for k in range(n) for l in range(n)), "maximize")

model.data = p,r
model.optimize()

sol = model.getBestSol()


# Print the solution on a readable format
Q = np.array([math.floor(model.getVal(model.data[0][key])) for key in model.data[0].keys()]).reshape([n,n])
print(f'\nOptimization ended with status {model.getStatus()} in {"{:.2f}".format(end_optimization-end_setup)}s, with {model.getObjVal()} increasing edges and optimal solution:')
print('\n',Q)
order = [int(x) for x in list(np.matmul(Q.T,np.array(range(n))))]
new_adj_t = adjacency_matrix(t,order)
print(f'\nwhich induces the ordering:\n\n {order}')
print(f'\nand induces the following adjacency matrix: \n\n {new_adj_t}')
```

Right now I've run it for n=5 taking between 5 and 20 seconds, and have ran it succesfully for small integers 6,7 with not much change in time needed.

For n=10, on the other hand, it has been running for around an hour with no solution yet, I suppose the linearization having O(n**4) variables hurts, but I don't understand why it blows up so fast. Is this normal? How would a better implementation be in case there is one?.

Comment: In the mathematical model, the constraint is incomplete. We only have an expression there.

Comment: oh right there's an equal sign missing before the last vector 1, it's fixed now

Comment: The constraint is just that the matrix Q is doubly stochastic (i.e. it's row-sums and column-sums equal 1).

Comment: It may be possible to add the `r<= p` only when needed (in a callback). See for TSP examples of how they add subtour-elimination constraints on the fly.